# При листании истории смещается позиция начала команды

Tags: bash

Я меняю строку приветствия с помощью скрипта в `/etc/profile.d/`

```
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
PS1='\u\[\e[0m\]@\h\[[\e[1;31m\]PROD\[\e[0;37m\]]\W\\$ '
fi
```

Но есть одна проблема когда нажимаешь вверх что бы выполнить предыдущую команду пропадает пробел после $
Вроде мелочь, но глаз дергается, как победить?

ps

```
 OS: CentOS Linux release 8.2.2004 (Core)
 Kernel: 4.18.0-147.8.1.el8_1.x86_64
 Shell: GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У меня не пропадает пробел, только цвета странно распределены.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

группируя некоторые последовательности символов (обычно это спец-коды для установки цвета) с помощью скобок `\[` и `\]`, вы подсказываете библиотеке [gnu/readline](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline), что данная последовательность символов при «отрисовке» не будет занимать ни одного знакоместа. это позволяет правильно рассчитывать длину приветствия и при «листании» истории выводить очередную команду в одной и той же позиции.

ошибка ваша находится здесь:

```
\[[\e[1;31m\]
```

внутрь группы у вас помещена не только (не занимающая ни одного знакоместа) последовательность `\e[1;31m` для установки красного цвета текста (`31`) и «жирного» написания (`1`), но и символ `[`, который должен выводиться «как есть», т.е., занимать знакоместо.

просто вынесите этот символ за пределы группы. судя по вашей задумке — перед ней:

```
[\[\e[1;31m\]
```